# Obj: Immediately return this expression instead of assigning it to the temporary variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops, sonarqube

```
  const whiteListUrls = await this.whiteListDomainsRepository.find({
    where: {and: [{isActive: true}, {type: 'redirect'}]},
  });
```

This whiteListUrls give a array like:

```
[
    WhiteListDomain {
    whiteListDomainId: '62b068307bed2ef2c57c4bbf',
    domain: 'go.pampers.com',
    isActive: true,
    type: 'redirect',
    createdDate: 2021-03-25T06:11:53.974Z,
    createdBy: 'thakkar.dt.1@pg.com',
    updatedBy: 'thakkar.dt.1@pg.com',
    updatedDate: 2021-03-25T06:13:53.545Z
    },
    WhiteListDomain {
    whiteListDomainId: '62b068f87bed2ef2c57c4bc0',
    domain: 'app.adjust.com',
    isActive: true,
    type: 'redirect',
    createdDate: 2021-03-25T06:11:53.974Z,
    createdBy: 'thakkar.dt.1@pg.com',
    updatedBy: 'thakkar.dt.1@pg.com',
    updatedDate: 2021-03-25T06:13:53.545Z
    }
]
```

The whiteListUrls returns **whiteListDomainId** I want to change that key name to ony **id**
Also we cannot overrwite whiteListUrls as it initialized from the db query.
So below is the approach i tried. But SonarQube error says **" obj: Immediately return this expression instead of assigning it to the temporary variable"**

```
  interface GetWhiteListesdUrls {
    id: string;
    domain: string;
    isActive: boolean;
    type: string;
    createdDate: string;
    createdBy: string;
    updatedDate: string;
    updatedBy: string;
  }

  const urls = whiteListUrls.map(element => {
    const obj: GetWhiteListesdUrls = {
      id: element.whiteListDomainId!,
      domain: element.domain,
      isActive: element.isActive!,
      type: element.type,
      createdDate: element.createdDate,
      createdBy: element.createdBy,
      updatedDate: element.updatedDate,
      updatedBy: element.updatedBy,
    };
    return obj;
  });
  return urls;
```

Is there any better optimized way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

> obj: Immediately return this expression instead of assigning it to the temporary variable

What that error means is that it wants you do this instead:

```
  return whiteListUrls.map(element => {
    const obj: GetWhiteListesdUrls = {
      id: element.whiteListDomainId!,
      domain: element.domain,
      isActive: element.isActive!,
      type: element.type,
      createdDate: element.createdDate,
      createdBy: element.createdBy,
      updatedDate: element.updatedDate,
      updatedBy: element.updatedBy,
    };
    return obj;
  });
```

Comment: this issue is for the obj inside map. Not for the whiteListUrls